# Django group manager getting each member roles

Tags: django

I have installed `django_group_manager` and I defined some members then allocated some roles from django admin panel. Now I want to print all member roles but can't:

```
>>> from groups_manager.models import Group, GroupType, Member

>>> member = Member.objects.get(username='myuser')
>>> member
<Member: test user>
```

How can I print each member roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query over the `GroupMemberRole` model:

```
from groups_manager.models import GroupMemberRole, Member

member = Member.objects.get(username='myuser')

roles = GroupMemberRole.objects.filter(
    groupmember__member=member
)

print(roles)
```

The [**`GroupMemberRole`** model [GitHub]](https://github.com/vittoriozamboni/django-groups-manager/blob/7ee8d75ad58d1396e82b584535412f9f67238ba9/groups_manager/models.py#L609-L612) inherits two fields `label` and `codename`, so you can for example enumerate over these and print the codename:

```
for role in roles:
    print(role.codename)
```

Comment: Here I have: `AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'roles'`

Comment: @M.J.: sorry confused group with member.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
members = Member.objects.all() # or any other query

for member in member:
    for role in member.role_set.all():
        print (role)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'Member' object is not iterable

Comment: you cant iterate through an object, if you use `member = Member.objects.get(username='myuser') you need to skip the first line in the loop, just user `for role in member.role_set.all(): print (role)`

Comment: `get` returns a single object while `filter` will return an iterable queryset of objects